# Will amazon-cloudfront follow a 308 redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on setting up amazon cloud front and have been playing around with the cache-control settings. It is explicitly stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-3xx-status-codes.html), that amazon-cloudfront will not follow a `301` and `307`.

I am wondering if there is documentation on if the redirect will be followed if the origin returns a `308`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little strange that 302 and 308 are not mentioned, here, but CloudFront does not follow redirects.  They are stored in the cache and returned to the browser.

You can intercept redirects with a Lambda@Edge response trigger, but the typical application for this is to rewrite the `Location` header and send the browser somewhere other than where it would otherwise have gone.

For small responses, it's possible to actually follow the redirect using an Origin Response trigger that makes a request using the Node HTTP client, but this only suports responses up to 1 MB in total size, and would probably not perform as well as simply letting the browser follow the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

There is some [additional documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomRedirects) here of handling redirects:

> If you change the location of an object on the origin server, you can
> configure your web server to redirect requests to the new location.
> After you configure the redirect, the first time a viewer submits a
> request for the object, CloudFront Front sends the request to the
> origin, and the origin responds with a redirect (for example, 302
> Moved Temporarily). CloudFront caches the redirect and returns it to
> the viewer. CloudFront does not follow the redirect.
>
> You can configure your web server to redirect requests to one of the
> following locations:
>
> ```
> The new URL of the object on the origin server. When the viewer follows the redirect to the new URL, the viewer bypasses CloudFront
> ```
>
> and goes straight to the origin. As a result, we recommend that you
> not redirect requests to the new URL of the object on the origin.
>
> ```
> The new CloudFront URL for the object. When the viewer submits the request that contains the new CloudFront URL, CloudFront gets the
> ```
>
> object from the new location on your origin, caches it at the edge
> location, and returns the object to the viewer. Subsequent requests
> for the object will be served by the edge location. This avoids the
> latency and load associated with viewers requesting the object from
> the origin. However, every new request for the object will incur
> charges for two requests to CloudFront.

But because `301` and `308` [only difference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538#page-3) is that `308`

> does not allow changing the request method from POST to GET

i would guess that it is handled like `301`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has since original post been updated to include info on 301, 302, 304, 307 and 308.